# Dynamically increasing height of content view of a scroll view in ios9

Tags: uiscrollview, swift2, ios9

I am struggling with this stuff for a few days. I am having a view controller in which I have a scroll view and above it a content view. In the content view I am displaying some text from web in a label. I am using a view controller of free form size 600*1000 for my designing purpose.I have given the following constraint to my content view -

1)pinned to the edges of scroll view.
2)content view width equals to superview width.
3)content view height equal to 900.

My scroll view is working perfect.
So now I want that whenever my text increases then my label size would increase thereby increasing the height of my content view automatically. So how to do so. Any answers are most welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the number of lines for your UILabel to 0.
2. Add leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints to UILabel.

Set number of lines to 0 does the trick, as the content increases UILabel will automatically adjust the height.

Comment: My content view is not increasing its size by the way.